# Submit form once with few forms on the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I want to have few forms on one page and do not reload it. I have actually one html file with two forms with submit input. I am using jQuery to remove (earlier hide) one form and show another one after clickin' on submit input. if i send two forms the result is doubled after minute from two forms. Even with preventDefault event method, returning false at the end and removing form. Here is the code:

```
formField.submit(function (event) {
    var newMark = {
      startingNumber: $("#startNum").val(),
      category1: $("#firstCat").val(),
      category2: $("#secondCat").val(),
      category3: $("#thirdCat").val(),
      category4: $("#forthCat").val(),
      category5:$("#fifthCat").val()
    };

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
$.ajax({
    url: "/horseRate",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: JSON.stringify(newMark),
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    success: function (data)
    {
        alert("OK" + data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err)
    {


    }
});
$( "#formField" ).remove();
formFieldTwo.show();
return false;

  });

  formFieldTwo.submit(function (event) {
  var newMarkTwo = {
    startingNumber: $("#startNum2").val(),
    category1: $("#firstCat2").val(),
    category2: $("#secondCat2").val(),
    category3: $("#thirdCat2").val(),
    category4: $("#forthCat2").val(),
    category5:$("#fifthCat2").val()
  };

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
$.ajax({
    url: "/horseRate",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: JSON.stringify(newMarkTwo),
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    success: function (data)
    {}
});

    $( "#formFieldTwo" ).remove();
    formFieldThree.show();
    return false;
  });
```

});
Any ideas please?

Comment: please show the according html

Comment: Setup a separate form on the same page place a hidden input for each piece of data you intend to post. Then submit that form and inhibit the actions on the other forms. Yeah, Axel is right, you'll need to post HTML as well, preferably in a snippet or fiddle.

Comment: Here's the html code. http://pastebin.com/HRNje8kx